# R - Using column value in data frame to lookup matrix name and summarize matrix

Tags: r, matrix, global

I am trying to add a new column to an existing data frame which shows the number of one's in a binary matrix. One column in the existing data frame has the the matrix names whose count/sum I am trying to find.

For example,

```
r <- 10
c <- 10
MatA <- matrix(sample(0:1,r*c, replace=TRUE),r,c)
MatB <- matrix(sample(0:1,r*c, replace=TRUE),r,c)
MatC <- matrix(sample(0:1,r*c, replace=TRUE),r,c)

mat <- c("MatA","MatB","MatC")
size <- c(4,6,10)
df <- data.frame(mat,size)
```

I need to lookup the `mat` column values such as `MatA, MatB, MatC` from `df` dataframe to match the matrix names `MatA, MatB, MatC` and return the number of 1's in each of the binary matrix added to the `df` dataframe in a new column.

I tried using loops, apply functions but am lost at how to use the column values `MatA` from `df$mat` as a lookup for matrix name `MatA` and return `sum(MatA==1)` to new column in dataframe `df`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `get` to reference variable by string

```
set.seed(7)
df$binary <- lapply(mat, function(x) sum(get(x)))
```

To use the data.frame column if stored as factors

```
df$binary <- lapply(levels(df$mat)[df$mat], function(x) sum(get(x)))
```

To store column as strings and not factors

```
df <- data.frame(mat, size, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df$binary <- lapply(df$mat, function(x) sum(get(x)))

> df
   mat size binary
1 MatA    4     47
2 MatB    6     58
3 MatC   10     54
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to use the `lapply` without using the `get` reference. It works beautifully.